# How to create purchase order via code?

Tags: acumatica

I had wrote some code for creating po via code, but it faild with error message: "CS Error: Cannot generate the next number for the sequence."

How can I fix this? Anything I missed? Thx for helping!

```
protected void createPO() {

  POOrder order = new POOrder();
  POOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance < POOrderEntry > ();
  order.OrderType = "Normal";
  order.OrderDesc = "some text";
  order.EmployeeID = 215;
  order.Hold = false;

  var branch = (Branch)PXSelect<Branch, Where<Branch.branchCD, Equal<Required<Branch.branchCD>>>>.Select(Base, "WEST");

  graph.FieldDefaulting.AddHandler<POOrder.branchID>((s, e) =>
  {
      e.NewValue = branch.BranchID;  
      e.Cancel = true;
  });

  order.VendorID = 79;
  order = graph.CurrentDocument.Insert(order);
  graph.CurrentDocument.Update(order);
  graph.Actions.PressSave();

  throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to simply it first to see if something like this works...

```
protected void createPO()
{
    var graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<POOrderEntry>();
    var order = graph.Document.Insert(new POOrder());

    order.OrderType = POOrderType.RegularOrder; // This is the default so not necessary
    order.OrderDesc = "some text";
    order.EmployeeID = 215;
    order.Hold = false;
    order.VendorID = 79;
    graph.Document.Update(order);
    graph.Actions.PressSave();

    throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, null);
}
```

Using the Document view in place of the CurrentDocument view which is based on the current record of Document. Document is the primary view and the primary view should be used.

Also for the purchase order type the attribute related to the list values should be used for the stored value of the database (vs what you had was the displayed list value). For example `order.OrderType = POOrderType.RegularOrder`. Also this is the default value for a PO so it is not necessary to set this value unless you want a different constant found in the `POOrderType` class.

Comment: Thx! It works. I'm a new developer working on Acumatica, I just wonder where can I find those code examples you give me, like create so,po and BQL examples. Do I need read the source code? Because I didn't found these on any manuals of Acumatica.

Comment: Its not going to be easy to find all examples but for this you can search the acumatica source for POOrderEntry. In summary figure out for a graph what are the least amount of fields i need to enter (not what defaults) and start there. In code fill in those fields and persist. I try to always insert an empty new object then update from there as the insert will set my defaults and then i can update them if needed. Hope that helps to answer your side question.

Comment: Good advice. I think I can learn Acumatica development in that way. Thx again!